# SecItemCopyMatching not returning System Root certificates

Tags: macos, ssl, keychain

I want to import the OSX/iOS certificates into an OpenSSL context at runtime.  To do this I am using SecItemCopyMatching with the following code to retrieve the certificates from the OS keychain:

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef attrDict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 4, NULL, NULL);
CFDictionaryAddValue(attrDict, kSecClass, kSecClassCertificate);        
CFDictionaryAddValue(attrDict, kSecReturnRef, kCFBooleanTrue);
CFDictionaryAddValue(attrDict, kSecMatchLimit, kSecMatchLimitAll);
CFDictionaryAddValue(attrDict, kSecMatchTrustedOnly, kCFBooleanTrue );

res = SecItemCopyMatching(attrDict, (CFTypeRef*)&certlist);
```

This seems to return the user and system certificates, but it does not return the contents of "System Roots" in the keychain.  How can I retrieve these a well?

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same problem and this is the solution that I found: Manually open System Roots keychain and add it to the search list for the query as follows:

```
SecKeychainRef systemRoots = NULL;
OSStatus kcStatus = SecKeychainOpen("/System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain", &systemRoots);

CFArrayRef currentSearchList;
SecKeychainCopySearchList(&currentSearchList);
CFMutableArrayRef newSearchList = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 5, currentSearchList);
CFRelease(currentSearchList);
if (!kcStatus) {
    CFArrayAppendValue(newSearchList, systemRoots);
}

CFMutableDictionaryRef attrDict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 5, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
CFDictionaryAddValue(attrDict, kSecMatchSearchList, newSearchList); // this is the important part
```

Comment: SecKeychain is not available on iOS, unfortunately.

Comment: Also, `SecKeychainOpen` method is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that typically certificates under System Roots are not marked as trusted. They are implicitly "trusted" because that keychain is read-only. So I'd suggest you use:

```
CFDictionaryAddValue(attrDict, kSecMatchTrustedOnly, kCFBooleanFalse );
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.